# How to retrieve data from two tables using the same sql statement?

Tags: sql, database

I'm making a food donation application. I have two tables. One to store the user information(called "user_info") that is collected from a registration form and the other(called "donated_info") is to store the details of the food.
Various fields of "user_info":

```
`user_id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `address`, `pincode`
```

Various fields of "donated_info":

```
`user_id`, `Food_id`, `Food_item`, `No_of_serving`, `Expiry_date`, `Expiry_time`, `Image`, `status`
```

I want to display the food details from "donated_info" and the address with pincode from "user_info" only those that correspond to the food seeker's pincode. How can I do it? I feel a bit confused. Any form of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup joins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a simple `inner join` assuming the `user_id` is the `key`

```
Select di.*, ui.address, ui.pincode
from user_info ui
join donated_info di on di.user_id=ui.user_Id
where ui.pincode=<pincode>
```